# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float':RK4 method using a function that outputs an array

Tags: python

I am writing a code for Rk4. I am writing it so that it works for a function that outputs an array that I call fb2 in my code(don't worry about the *args they are there for a purpose not shown in this section I cut from my code). I keep getting this error at the line K2=.... and I changed h to int(h) because I thought that would help but it's still upset. How do I fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fb2(t,J):
x=J[0]
y=J[1]
dxdt=0.25*y-x
dydt=3*x-y
#X0,Y0=1,1 initial conditions
return([dxdt,dydt])



#x0 and y0 are initial conditions

def odeRK4(function,tspan,R,h,*args):

    #R is vector of inital conditions
    x0=R[0]
    y0=R[1]


    #writing statement for what to do if h isnt given/other thing
    if h==None:
        h=.01*(tspan[1]-tspan[0])
    elif h> tspan[1]-tspan[0]:
        h=.01*(tspan[1]-tspan[0])
    else:
        h=h
    #defining the 2-element array (i hope)
    #pretty sure tspan is range of t values
    x0=tspan[0] #probably 0 if this is meant for time
    xn=tspan[1] #whatever time we want it to end at?
    #xn is final x value-t
    #x0 is initial

    t_values=np.arange(x0,xn+h,h) #range of values based on increments of h
    N=len(t_values)
    y_val=np.zeros(N)
    y_val[0]=y0
    #I am trying to print all the Y values into this array
    if function==fb2:
        y_val=np.zeros([2,N])#makes 2 vectors, this makes it possible for : to apply
        y_val[:,0]=y0
        h=int(h)
        for i in range(1,N):
            #rk4 method
            k1=function(t_values[i-1],y_val[:,i-1],*args)
            k2=function(t_values[i-1]+0.5*h,y_val[:,i-1]+0.5*k1*h,*args)
            k3=function(t_values[i-1]+0.5*h,y_val[:,i-1]+0.5*k2*h,*args)
            k4=function(t_values[i-1]+h,y_val[:,i-1]+k3*h,*args)
            y_val[:,i]=y_val[:,i-1]+h*(1/6)*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
            #this fills the t_val array and keeps the loop going

        a=np.column_stack((t_values,y_val))
        print('At time t, Y= (t on left,Y on right)')
        print(a)
        plt.plot(t_values,y_val)

print('for 3B:')
odeRK4(fb2,[0,20],[1,1],None)
```

Comment: `k2=function(t_values[i-1]+0.5*h,y_val[:,i-1]+0.5*k1*h,*args)` Well, the problem pretty much has to be either `h` or `k1`.  Have you tried printing those variables to see what they are?

Comment: @JohnGordon k1 is a list and h is not. I did h=int(h) but it still doesn't work and has the same typeerror message